Navbar aspect-ratio is wrong i have made changes in tailwind.config.js but still same issue ( am new to tailwind)
this is the navbar after I run the app 
the navbar should be on the top like this-
https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation
[Navigation.jsx & tailwind.config.js screenshots]
(https://i.sstatic.net/Sq3Vm.png)
check the code screenshot which I have provided and made changes as asked in the code but the navbar ratio issue is not solved yet
